# LuaLaTeX + unicode-math results in wrong \mkern and \mskip

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, kerning

In a personal package I tested `\mkern` and `\mskip` for different values using pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, I discovered that the spacing using `\mkern0mu` and `\mskip0mu` seems to leave a negative space of `-1.1mu`. This is shown in the mwe below. Removing `unicode-math` gives the correct space. However using XeLaTeX with and without `unicode-math` gives the correct space, same for pdfLaTeX and amsmath. Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

    $\partial \mkern 1.1mu t = \partial t \neq \partial \mkern 0mu t$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: comparison with `\showoutput` of xelatex and lualatex shows that in former case there is always after the `\partial` a `\kern0.63` which however in the latter engine disappears as soon as one uses `\mkern`.

Comment: I would guess the `\kern0.63` is an italic correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When \mkern is used the default (italic) kern is removed. You can set `\mathitalicsmode=1` to change this behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
    $\partial \mkern 1.1mu t = \partial t \neq \partial \mkern 0mu t$

\mathitalicsmode=1

    $\partial \mkern 1.1mu t = \partial t \neq \partial \mkern 0mu t$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so, you mean is removed by luatex or by unicode-math? because it shows with xelatex.

Comment: @jfbu by luatex (luatex's treatment of math italic correction is very different from that of classic tex or xetex)

Comment: \mathitalicsmode is a primitive of luatex.